# Find distance between touch and textview in android

Tags: java, android

I am designing an android app, and one thing I would like to happen is when the user clicks the page, I would like to find the distance between where they clicked and a `TextView` element on the page. So far, what I have done is set the `TextView` ID by using

```
android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
```

I know I also need to use `android:onTouch` coordinates somehow, but I am not sure how to incorporate this into the coordinates of my `TextView`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can put a touch listener on the whole activity and calculate the distance like this.

```
public void onCreate() {
    setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);
    ...
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
    View mainView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    mainView.setonTouchListener(new View.onTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int rawX = event.getRawX();
            int rawY = event.getRawY();
            int location[] = new int[2];
            textView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

            int distanceX = location[0] - rawX;
            int distanceY = location[1] - rawY;

            // Do something with the distance.
            return false;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```